# Unable to programmatically add a UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I recently converted my .xib file to Storyboards and decided to programmatically add a `UITableView` to my `ViewController` in the storyboard.

I used this code to accomplish this:

```
// ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    UITableView *table;
}



// ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (PrivateStuff)
// unimportant code...
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    table.delegate = self;
    table.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:table];
}
```

Unfortunately, whenever I try to run it, Xcode is giving me this message...

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "ViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

... which doesn't make any sense. I have everything that needs to be hooked up on its correct order and all of my other views with `UITableView`s have no problem, in spite that the code is the same.

What could I do to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got something hooked up in the storyboard? make sure you remove any links if you are programatically creating them.

Comment: how are you loading the view?

Comment: The error refers to a UITableViewController and a xib file. Do you have a UITAbleViewController in your app (or did you have one that you deleted)?

Comment: @rdelmar I still have the .nib file, but I would like to delete it once I know the storyboard is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @rdelmar-Xcode is saying that a nib was loaded during a `[tableviewcontroller loadView]` call-so that means there is a tableviewcontroller somewhere in your code...but it also means that somehow the nib you created is still linked to your view controller.  You may need to look at the connections inspector under utilities in Xcode and see if your nib still has any persistent links present and delete them.  Otherwise, as long as you are providing a TableViewCell, either custom or generic, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, the above code should work

Comment: Thank you for that response. I looked at `ViewController.xib` but I saw no such connection. So I restored an earlier version through Dropbox, and removed the connection from there. Once I ran the app, it worked without any problems. Thanks for your help.